# How to repeatedly sample from two time windows with dplyr's `slice_sample`?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the `dplyr::slice_sample` function in R to randomly select one time point for each of two time windows (lets say: `W1`:from 10mins to 2hrs  and `W2`: 2.5hrs to 4.5hrs) from the whole dataset that spans 5hrs.
How can I do that?

I have tried using the Slice_sample function as follows:

```r
data %>% group_by(dataID)%>% slice_sample(n=2)
```

and I get two timepoints but they aren't in the windows I want(sometimes I get two in the same window)

Comment: You could do something like `bind_rows(data |> filter(W1_TIME_VARIABLE_IN_MINS >= 10, W1_TIME_VARIABLE_IN_MINS < 120) |> slice_sample(n=1), data |> filter(W2_TIME_VARIABLE_IN_MINS >= 150, W2_TIME_VARIABLE_IN_MINS < 270) |> slice_sample(n=1))` to pull random rows from each time range. (There are loads of ways you could have your time stored so I'm just showing for one possibility.)  Then you could make a `for` loop or use `replicate` to run the sampling as many times as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used this with some modifications and I got what I needed.